# C# calling the Process.Start() create another instance of the program

Tags: c#, winforms

this is my first post here so forgive me for my mistakes.
I'm currently developping a program for myself. It is a C# winform app. You just fill the hours/minutes/seconds input and I then want it to shutdown the computer at that given amount of time later. So I coded the basics to convert the amount of time in seconds ( as the batch only accepts seconds ). I even ran the .exe in a windows 10 virtual machine but There's a problem with my call :

```
private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           seconds =  convertToSeconds();
           Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t " + seconds);
        }
```

Calling this function just run another instance of this .exe.
at first, I thought it was because adding "+ seconds" was wrong and there was another way of doing it but even cancelling the shutdown with this code runs another instance of the .exe :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long seconds = 0;
            DateTime shutdownDate = default(DateTime);
            Process.Start("shutdown", "/a");
        }
```

Here is a screenshot of the app if you didn't understand how it works :
http://puu.sh/qkUi0/f2c1ad00ad.png

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: You might be better off using a process start info parameter instead of strings [see the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it stills open another instance of the app.

Comment: See if answer of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751860/run-process-in-current-console) helps.

Comment: I am guessing your application name is also shutdown.exe. Is it?

Comment: There are other ways if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp

Comment: Oh my god yes it is. I knew I made a dumb mistake. Let me rename everything and give you an update

Comment: yea that was it now it works like a charm.